# Raspberry Pi not booting and may be damaged

Tags: boot-issues, pi-1

My Rapsberry Pi 1 is damaged. The Broadcom chip gets very hot and only the red LED glows with green LED blinking randomly.What should I do with the Raspberry PI.

Comment: `the red LED glows with green LED blinking randomly` - sounds like an operational pi to me

Comment: How hot is the room where you are using the Pi? what OS is running on the Pi? And what have you been using it for?

Comment: How do you know that it is broken?, what steps have you taken to diagnose your problem? What are you attempting to do that is not working, because as @jaromandax said the led functions you are describing are that of a working Pi, and the Pi is designed to get pretty hot, as it is a cpu similar to that found in phones, the only difference being your mobile phone has a case which prevents you from noticing how hot it really gets

Comment: @Darth Vader I am working with pi in room temperature of about 36-38 Celsius. I m using raspbian and using it to drive motor IC (L293D)

Comment: @Mohammad Ali My pi gets really hot as i'm applying power through my laptop's usb port. It doesnot boot up and no output is shown on screen.

Comment: try using a better power source such as a phone charger, because "really hot" isn't very descriptive, but a solid red light should be a sign of low power. as in not enough amps being supplied, as your laptop is designed to output .5 amps where as the pi needs around an amp to operate, its similar to how most tablets won't be able to charge off a laptop, because the power being supplied isn't enough. Also what kind of display output are you using?

Comment: @RAJKUMARMISHRA, running a Pi off a USB port from a laptop can  result in permanently damaging your port. As suggested above, getting a 5v, 1A+ (must also take into consideration what peripherals you are connecting to the Pi when selecting the current rating) phone charger is highly recommended.

Comment: @RAJKUMARMISHRA In addition to using a proper power supply, since youre using the Pi in a very warm environment, and are noting how warm it gets, try attaching a heatsink to the processor chip (I use 1.25 in quarters glued together)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments for your question I suggest using a power supply for the pi like a phone charger which plugs into the wall socket. This should stop the under-power problems you are having. This may get the SD card working and you may get an image on the screen. If nothing appears on the screen first check the screen input otherwise the SD card may be corrupted and needs to be re-flashed.

Other options include trying the SD card in another pi which is known to be working to test if the card is corrupted. If it boots then the problem lies in the power supply. If it doesn't the problem is with the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

That may be a stupid question, but did you disconnect everything from your Pi? I remember fiddling with one of mine "punch bag" Pi when it was on, shorting pins by mistake and it just shuts down and plays dead (on board LEDs suggesting that everything is A-OK)
As soon as I de-shorted it - came back alive as if nothing happened.
Try to power it on with just a screen plugged in.

Answer (score -2):

Is the red LED on permanently? That usually denotes a power issue. I'd try a different power source. It may also be the case that the SD card is corrupted (this can be caused by bad power supplies), I'd reflash your OS on a new sd card too.

Comment: This is just wrong.  The red led being on constantly is normal; on some models if it intermittently *goes out* that indicates insufficient power.  Further, the red led does not indicate anything about the state of the SD card, although red on/green off on a model 1 would indicate the SD card is invalid or missing (because the green led is out).  The green led blinking intermittently (as per the question) indicates the SD card is valid and in use.